# Replacing string in a specific position between known delimiters in shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, vi

I have a file with data stored in this format

> ```
> ID;Name;Surname;Country
> ```

And I need to be able to find and replace a specific piece of data just knowing the ID and the position of the data using ';' as delimiters.

Kind of like the result of

> grep -n "ID" [file] | cut -d ";" -f [position]

But replacing with a user given string instead of displaying

I reckon I need to use sed but nothing I've found has worked.

Edit: The user would come from a menu where they'd pick what to modify and provide the ID, they would then be prompted to type the replacement string and knowing the structure of the stored data (ID/Name/Surname/Country) the string would be replaced accordingly in the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with awk:

```
echo 'ID;Data1;Data2;Data3' | awk -v id="ID" -v col=3 -v repl="foo" -F';' 'BEGIN{OFS=";";} $1==id {$col=repl;}1'
```

Output:

```
ID;Data1;foo;Data3
```

Comment: Thanks, should I just redirect the whole thing to the file to make it permanent or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I suggest to redirect its output to a file: `awk ... > new_file`